# Deleting an Asset

Tags: twilio

I created a Flex UI plugin for recording calls, I accidently uploaded it as Private, so I removed it and uploaded again as Public.

However, when I check Flex UI, I see the plugin deployed twice. Even though there is only one asset.

I checked the Asset API and I can see the duplicate assets there, but there isn't any documentation on how to delete an asset.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is probably an asset version.[Asset Versions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions-assets-api/api/asset-version) are like instances of different uploads attached to the assets. You can delete both an asset and particular or all asset versions. Asset versions contain history of all the uploads happening to the asset.